# Change time of WordPress cron with php code

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am writing a plugin which should automatically send email at certain time a day. This time should the user be able change in setting. I have currently a textbox with the requested time and when a user makes change of it and save the setting I delete the cron and create a new one with the new time.
There is a problem - when creating the new cron the calling function gets fired even thou it should be fired later that day. That means that the cron fires the same function twice.
This is the code:

```
function email_run_cron()
{
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'email_cron' );

    $options = get_option('email_options');
    if (isset($options['enabled'])) {           
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'email_cron' ) ) {
            add_action( 'email_cron', 'email_event' );
            if (isset($options['send_time'])) {
                $tm = strtotime($options['send_time']);
            } else {
                $tm = time();
            }
            wp_schedule_event( $tm, 'daily', 'email_cron' );
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot fin a function which would simply change the time of existing cron. What is the best solution for this, please?

Comment: And you are sure that `send_time` is really stored in `email_options`? I am thinking, if it is not then the above will always schedule a job to run at the current time.

Comment: Take a look at the [`cron.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.3/src/wp-includes/cron.php), there's other functions such as `wp_reschedule_event` in there.

Comment: Yes, it is there. I also double checked that the cron is set for the same time as stored in options.

Comment: CBroe: this changes the cron time but the function gets called anyway at the change time.

Answer (score 0):

I find out what was going on:

`add_action()` should be called after `wp_schedule_event()`.

So code is like:

```
function email_run_cron()
{
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'email_cron' );

    $options = get_option('email_options');
    if (isset($options['enabled'])) {           
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'email_cron' ) ) {
            if (isset($options['send_time'])) {
                $tm = strtotime($options['send_time']);
            } else {
                $tm = time();
            }
            wp_schedule_event( $tm, 'daily', 'email_cron' );
            add_action( 'email_cron', 'email_event' );
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works fine.